# Sorting blocks of lines

Tags: text-processing, sort

I have a file that contains 4n lines. Here is an excerpt from it containing 8 lines

```
6115 8.88443
6116 6.61875
6118 16.5949
6117 19.4129
6116 6.619 
6117 16.5979 
6118 19.4111
6115 8.88433
```

What I want to do is sort a block, where each block consists of 4 lines based on the first column. The output for the excerpt should look as shown below.

```
6115 8.88443
6116 6.61875
6117 19.4129
6118 16.5949
6115 8.88433 
6116 6.619 
6117 16.5979 
6118 19.4111
```

Answer (score 17):

One options is to use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) to add an initial serial number prefix every N lines (N=4 in your case).  Then feed the prefix as the primary sorting column into `sort`.

Example with N=4:

```
awk '{print int((NR-1)/4), $0}' file.txt | sort -n -k1,1 -k2,2 | cut -f2- -d' '
```

Answer (score 7):

If this is a one off and you don't want to learn python, perl or awk, you can go with the basic `split` and `sort` commands.

First split the file in 4 line chunks with the `-l`  option:

```
split -a 6 -l 4 input_file my_prefix_
for fn in my_prefix_*; do
    sort -n -o $fn $fn
done
cat my_prefix_* > output_file
rm my_prefix_*
```

The `sort -n` sorts by numerical value of the first column (999 before 1234).
`-a 6` should take care of a file with 26^6*4 lines. `my_prefix_` should be something unique to the directory you work with.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with Perl:

```
perl -nle '
   push @a,$_;
   unless($. % 4){
       print join "\n",sort {$a <=> $b} @a; # Sort @a, and print its contents
       @a = (); # Empty @a to start a new block
   }
' your_file
```

**How this works**

- `-n` --> run the code for each input line (and put the current line in `$_`)
- `-l` --> append a newline to the output of any `print`
- `-e` --> execute the following string as Perl code
- Each line is appended to the array `@a`.
- `$.` holds the current line number and unless that number is not congruent to zero modulo 4, then we keep working. If it *is* congruent to zero modulo 4, we have reached a line whose number is a multiple of 4 (the end of a block), in which case, we sort the entries in `@a` in ascending numerical order and print the entries in the sorted array joined by a newline to standard output.

Answer (score 2):

Using a Bourne-like shell,

```
while read a ; do                                           # Try reading a line.
    read b ; read c ; read d                                # OK, read 3 more.
    printf '%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n' "$a" "$b" "$c" "$d" | sort -n # Sort them.
done < data
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are some "pure" `awk` solutions:

If the indexes are always the same incrementing integer sequence (6115-6119), as in your sample-data, you can use an algorithmic "shortcut":

```
awk '{a[$1]=$0} !(NR%4){for(i=6115;i<6119;print a[i++]);}'
```

This does

- Add all lines to the array `a`, distributed at index positions 6115-6119
- On every 4th line (`!(NR%4)`) , loop through the array contents to print in the desired order.

---

If your numeric indexes are always the four same ones, but not an incrementing integer sequence, you'll have to sort:

```
awk '{a[$1]=$0} !(NR%4){asort(a,b); for(i=1;i<5;print b[i++]);}'
```

Note: This is with GNU awk, others may not support `asort`.

---

If every block-of-four could have different numeric IDs:

```
awk '{a[$1]=$0} !(NR%4){asort(a); for(i=1;i<5;print a[i++]); delete a}'
```

Note: TIL from [@Gilles self-answer(+2) this use of `delete` is not (yet) POSIX, but universally supported](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147957/delete-an-array-in-awk).

---

A version with the correct™ use of `delete`:

```
awk '{a[$1]=$0} !(NR%4){asort(a); for(i=1;i<5;delete a[i++]){print a[i]}}'
```

A version without delete, using more memory and dimensions:

```
awk '{a[n][$1]=$0} !(NR%4){asort(a[n]); for(i=1;i<5;print a[n][i++]); n++}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a clean solution with R. If the table above is in a file called "table.txt", then perform the following steps. The desired result will be in the file "tableout.txt".

```
> x = read.table("table.txt", col.names=c("a", "b"))
> x
     a        b
1 6115  8.88443
2 6116  6.61875
3 6118 16.59490
4 6117 19.41290
5 6116  6.61900
6 6117 16.59790
7 6118 19.41110
8 6115  8.88433
> x["index"] = c(rep(1, 4), rep(2, 4))
> x
     a        b index
1 6115  8.88443     1
2 6116  6.61875     1
3 6118 16.59490     1
4 6117 19.41290     1
5 6116  6.61900     2
6 6117 16.59790     2
7 6118 19.41110     2
8 6115  8.88433     2     
> xord = x[with(x, order(index, a)), ]
> xord
     a        b index
1 6115  8.88443     1
2 6116  6.61875     1
4 6117 19.41290     1
3 6118 16.59490     1
8 6115  8.88433     2
5 6116  6.61900     2
6 6117 16.59790     2
7 6118 19.41110     2
> write.table(xord[,1:2], "tableout.txt", row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
```

See also [How to sort a dataframe by column(s) in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1296646/350713).