# repeated value in .csv file

Tags: text-processing, awk, scripting, csv

everybody, I've got this script that I've used without any problem until now, it uses two files in order to create a .csv, those two files came from another script and it contains information about devices connected to a network, this is how the files look when the error is caused.

file1.dat:

```
SN: FCQ1632Y0UQ
Estadio_Admon
ip_address: 148.000.000.123
```

file2.dat:

```
Device ID: ESTADIO_19
IP address: 148.000.000.119
Interface: FastEthernet0/3
Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0

Device ID: ESTADIO_18
IP address: 148.000.000.118
Interface: FastEthernet0/4
Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0

Device ID: ESTADIO_16
IP address: 148.000.000.116
Interface: FastEthernet0/6
Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0

Device ID: ESTADIO_PALCOS
IP address: 148.000.000.66
Interface: GigabitEthernet0/2
Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/1
SN: FCQ1632Y0US

Device ID: ESTADIO_22
IP address: 148.000.000.122
Interface: FastEthernet0/8
Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0

Device ID: SIPCCEF485DE89A
IP address: 148.000.000.92
Interface: FastEthernet0/16
Port ID (outgoing port): Port 1

Device ID: SIPCCEF485DE87B
IP address: 148.000.000.72
Interface: FastEthernet0/13
Port ID (outgoing port): Port 1

Device ID: SIPCCEF485E5719
IP address: 148.000.000.76
Interface: FastEthernet0/17
Port ID (outgoing port): Port 1

Device ID: SIPCCEF485DE894
IP address: 148.000.000.84
Interface: FastEthernet0/14
Port ID (outgoing port): Port 1

Device ID: ESTADIO_TAQUILLAS
IP address: 148.000.000.125
Interface: GigabitEthernet0/1
Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet1/0/27
SN: FOC1616Y091
```

script:

```
awk -v orig=$(awk '$1=="SN:" {print $2}' file1.dat) '
    BEGIN {
        RS = "\n\n"                                               
        FS = "\n"                                                 
        OFS = ","                                                 
        print "Device_SN_O,Device_SN_D,Interface,Port_ID"         
    }                                                             

    {                                                             
        for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {                                    
            split($i, a, ": ");                                   
            k[a[1]] = a[2]                                        
        }                                                         
        print orig, k["SN"], k["Interface"], k["Port ID (outgoing port)"]
    }' file2.dat>final.csv
```

expected output:

```
Device_SN_O,Device_SN_D,Interface,Port_ID
FCQ1632Y0UQ,,FastEthernet0/3,GigabitEthernet0
FCQ1632Y0UQ,,FastEthernet0/4,GigabitEthernet0
FCQ1632Y0UQ,,FastEthernet0/6,GigabitEthernet0
FCQ1632Y0UQ,FCQ1632Y0US,GigabitEthernet0/2,GigabitEthernet0/1
FCQ1632Y0UQ,,FastEthernet0/8,GigabitEthernet0
FCQ1632Y0UQ,,FastEthernet0/16,Port 1
FCQ1632Y0UQ,,FastEthernet0/13,Port 1
FCQ1632Y0UQ,,FastEthernet0/17,Port 1
FCQ1632Y0UQ,,FastEthernet0/14,Port 1
FCQ1632Y0UQ,FOC1616Y091,GigabitEthernet0/1,GigabitEthernet1/0/27
```

the output I've got:

```
Device_SN_O,Device_SN_D,Interface,Port_ID
FCQ1632Y0UQ,,FastEthernet0/3,GigabitEthernet0
FCQ1632Y0UQ,,FastEthernet0/4,GigabitEthernet0
FCQ1632Y0UQ,,FastEthernet0/6,GigabitEthernet0
FCQ1632Y0UQ,FCQ1632Y0US,GigabitEthernet0/2,GigabitEthernet0/1
FCQ1632Y0UQ,FCQ1632Y0US,FastEthernet0/8,GigabitEthernet0
FCQ1632Y0UQ,FCQ1632Y0US,FastEthernet0/16,Port 1
FCQ1632Y0UQ,FCQ1632Y0US,FastEthernet0/13,Port 1
FCQ1632Y0UQ,FCQ1632Y0US,FastEthernet0/17,Port 1
FCQ1632Y0UQ,FCQ1632Y0US,FastEthernet0/14,Port 1
FCQ1632Y0UQ,FOC1616Y091,GigabitEthernet0/1,GigabitEthernet1/0/27
```

As you can see, the Device_SN_D is being repeated until a different one is found, I've used the same script in different iterations and this is the first that gives me this error.

Hope you can help me with this.

Comment: You say it used to do the right thing? What changed?

Comment: File1.dat and File2.dat are always changing, the 'structure' is the same 
(Supposedly) I will update the question with a succeed output example.

Comment: you are right @RakeshSharma there were missed info. but I just edit the post.

Comment: You need to reinitialize the array `k[...]` for each line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your data doesn't have any "SN: ....." , you do not assign k["SN"] an empty value, so the last value is still in there.

You just need to add a :  `delete k` (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/147958/27616) just before processing the next line, so that the next line is processed with a "fresh k array"

For exemple:

```
awk -v orig=$(awk '$1=="SN:" {print $2}' file1.dat) '
BEGIN {
    RS = "\n\n"                                               
    FS = "\n"                                                 
    OFS = ","                                                 
    print "Device_SN_O,Device_SN_D,Interface,Port_ID"         
}                                                             

{                                                             
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {                                    
        split($i, a, ": ");                                   
        k[a[1]] = a[2]                                        
    }                                                         
    print orig, k["SN"], k["Interface"], k["Port ID (outgoing port)"]
    delete k;  rem="So that the next line is processed with an emptied k array"
}' file2.dat>final.csv
```

On your provided data it gives in final.csv:

```
Device_SN_O,Device_SN_D,Interface,Port_ID
FCQ1632Y0UQ,,FastEthernet0/3,GigabitEthernet0
FCQ1632Y0UQ,,FastEthernet0/4,GigabitEthernet0
FCQ1632Y0UQ,,FastEthernet0/6,GigabitEthernet0
FCQ1632Y0UQ,FCQ1632Y0US,GigabitEthernet0/2,GigabitEthernet0/1
FCQ1632Y0UQ,,FastEthernet0/8,GigabitEthernet0
FCQ1632Y0UQ,,FastEthernet0/16,Port 1
FCQ1632Y0UQ,,FastEthernet0/13,Port 1
FCQ1632Y0UQ,,FastEthernet0/17,Port 1
FCQ1632Y0UQ,,FastEthernet0/14,Port 1
FCQ1632Y0UQ,FOC1616Y091,GigabitEthernet0/1,GigabitEthernet1/0/27
```

as expected