# Print structured list to command-line (tree like)

Tags: text-processing, command-line, tree

If I have a text-file with a structured list like this:

```
#linux
##audio
###sequenzer
####qtractor
###drummachine
####hydrogen

##scores
###lilypond
###musescore

##bureau
###kalender
####calcurse
###todo
####tudu
```

How can I print it `tree` like to the command-line?

```
linux/
├── audio
│   ├── drummachine
│   │   └── hydrogen
│   └── sequenzer
│       └── qtractor
├── bureau
│   ├── kalender
│   │   └── calcurse
│   └── todo
│       └── tudu
└── scores
    ├── lilypond
    └── musescore
```

**Is there an application that I'm missing out?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `awk` to convert the structure to "normal" pathes.

```
linux/
linux/audio/
linux/audio/sequenzer/
linux/audio/sequenzer/qtractor/
linux/audio/drummachine/
linux/audio/drummachine/hydrogen/
...
```

Then you can use `tree --fromfile .` to read it:

---

`convert_structure.awk`:

```c
{
    delete path_arr
    path = ""
    level=match($0,/[^#]/)-1
    sub(/^#*/,"")
    p[level]=$0
    for (l=1;l<=level;l++) {
        path_arr[l]=p[l]
        path = path p[l] "/"
    }
    print path
}
```

**RUN**:

```bsh
awk -f convert_structure.awk structure.txt | tree --fromfile . --noreport
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
.
└── linux
    ├── audio
    │   ├── drummachine
    │   │   └── hydrogen
    │   └── sequenzer
    │       └── qtractor
    ├── bureau
    │   ├── kalender
    │   │   └── calcurse
    │   └── todo
    │       └── tudu
    └── scores
        ├── lilypond
        └── musescore
```

---

**Notes**:

- Check [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147957/delete-an-array-in-awk) if your implementation of `awk` does not support `delete` of an array.
- This works fine with pathes that include spaces, but obviously won't work with pathes inlcuding newlines.

Comment: You can always use `split("", path_arr)` if `delete path_arr` is not supported (`delete` is standard, it's passing it an array as a whole that used not to be).

Comment: I'm on cygwin where `tree --version` outputs  `tree v1.7.0 (c) 1996 - 2014 by Steve Baker, Thomas Moore, Francesc Rocher, Florian Sesser, Kyosuke Tokoro` and it doesn't have a `--fromfile` option (or any other that'd let it take such input as far as I can see). What `tree` version are you using?

Comment: -> `tree v1.8.0`

Comment: This goes a bit beyond the original question, but is there a way of keeping the order of the *scructered-list* rather then getting an *alphabetical order* as if it was a `directory-list`?